# How to add mapper to JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize to get custom(minified) json without using [JsonProperty("")]?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, mapper, javascriptserializer

I want to customize JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize by adding mapping.
Make it clear:

Think we have class:(as it comes from other library I can't modify this class, so I can not use  [JsonProperty("")] )

```
class Address
{
     public string Number { get; set; }
     public string Street { get; set; }
     public string City { get; set; }
     public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

output should be:

```
{
         "NMB" : "No 25",
         "STR" : "Main Street",
         "CTY" : "Matale",
         "CNT" : "Sri Lanka"
 }
```

How can I achieve mapping during           `JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Address_Object);`?

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` has not been ported to .NET Core.  Are you certain you are not open to switching to another serializer, like System.Text.Json or Json.NET?

Comment: I can use other serializer library, but the question is still about mapping during serialization

Comment: If you use System.Text.Json or Json.NET it may be easier just to write a custom converter + DTO instead of using AutoMapper.  Is your actual class much larger than the one shown so that you want something declarative?

Comment: Yes, my classes are so larger than this.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the simpliest way would be to create an util to serialize, you can use a net serializer, or a Newtonsoft.Json one

```
var addr = new Address {....}
string json = SerializeAddress(addr);

public string SerializeAddress(Address address)
{
    var addr = new
    {
        NMB = address.Number,
        STR = address.Street,
        CTY = address.City,
        CNT = address.Country
    };

    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(addr, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    //Or
    return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(addr);
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but as I have nested classes, it wont work for me. Is there any convenient way if I have nested classes, and I just want to modify attributes in nested one?

Comment: @ozziem Your common sense should tell you that it is impossible that compiller will guess which properties should be mapped. Mapper can work automaticaly ONLY if both properties have the same name.

Comment: @ozziem You can parse object and  change only some parts of it, but it is going to make code wery confusing. I think that it is more clear just to use the same algorithm for everything.

Comment: ok so do you know how to add [JsonProperty("")] dynamically? or need to ask other question?

Comment: @ozziem I want you not to waste our time,  in the future post the real code and ask the real question immediately, don't change your question every minute. Nobody is going to spend the whole day with you.